# Very silly doubt about homotopy invariance of integral

Tags: complex-analysis

In pp 93-95 of Stein-Sharkarchi, we get the following theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function on some domain $\Omega$ and let $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$ be closed, piecewise $C^1$ curves. If $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are homotopic then 
>   $$
> \int_{\gamma_0} f(z)\,dz = \int_{\gamma_1} f(z)\,dz.
> $$

I have a very silly doubt:

Gluing $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ together forms a closed loop $\gamma$, and since $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = 0$ for any closed loop (because $f$ is holomorphic), don't we trivially get $0 = \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_0} f(z) dz - \int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz$ ?

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but you are right that it's basically equivalent to say integrals around loops in $\Omega$ are trivial and that integrals in $\Omega$ are path-independent. So perhaps the authors  haven't yet proven the theorem that the integral of $f(z)dz$ on any closed loop vanishes?

Comment: @hunter Um doesn't that follows from the fact the integral of $f$ over any triangle vanishes and thus you can define the antiderivative of $f$ ? And yeah this was proved way earlier; the books proof is sketched here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904790/confusion-about-proving-homotopy-invariance-of-the-contour-integral

Comment: @Masacroso Your first sentence is very very false.

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is not valid. Integral of a holomorphic function over a closed loop is $0$ if the domain is **simply connected**. It is not given here that $\Omega$ is simply connected so your proof fails.

[Integral of $\frac 1 z$ over the unit circle is $2 \pi i \neq 0$ even though $\frac 1 z$ is analytic in the domain $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}]$.